# Call a sub when a cell is a certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to call my sub that causes a cell to blink between red and white if the value of cell N63 = 0. So in other words, if cell `D70 = 0` then StartBlinking else StopBlinking.

Here is the Bliking sub

```
Option Explicit

Public NextBlink As Double
'The cell that you want to blink
Public Const BlinkCell As String = "Sheet1!D70"

'Start blinking
Public Sub StartBlinking()
    Application.Goto Range("A1"), 1
    'If the color is red, change the color and text to white
    If Range(BlinkCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Range(BlinkCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Range(BlinkCell).Value = "White"
    'If the color is white, change the color and text to red
    Else
        Range(BlinkCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Range(BlinkCell).Value = "Red"
    End If
    'Wait one second before changing the color again
    NextBlink = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime NextBlink, "StartBlinking", , True
End Sub

'Stop blkinking
Public Sub StopBlinking()
    'Set color to white
    Range(BlinkCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    'Clear the value in the cell
    'Range(BlinkCell).ClearContents
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime NextBlink, "StartBlinking", , False
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Here is my `if` that does not work:

```
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N63").Value = 0 Then
        Call StartBlink()
    Else
        Call StopBlink()
    End If
```

How do I call these two subs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking advantage of the [Worksheet_Change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) you can run some code for each change to a particular range. Below is an example tailored to your use-case:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("D70")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If KeyCells.Value = 0 Then 
            StartBlinking
        Else 
            StopBlinking
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful. Does the Blinking Methods have to be `public`? amd should I place the methods for blinking in the a module file thing or just below the `Worksheet_Change` sub

Comment: This assumes that you are changing the sheet. If the cell changes based on formula then `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` is also an option. If you put the methods in a module then you need to fully qualify the ranges so it knows which range to update. Eg `Public Sub StartBlinking(byval ws as worksheet)... ws.Range(BlinkCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: You're welcome. The blinking subroutines can be either Public or Private. If you choose to make them Private they should remain on the worksheet with the worksheet-specific code shown in my answer.